# Whats the difference between GetLogicalDrives and FindFirstVolume+FindNextVolume?

Tags: winapi, volume, hard-drive, difference

It seems that I do not quite understand the differences between Microsoft's definition to "Logical Drive" and "Volume".

Is every logical drive a volume but not the other way around ?

I would love to get an explanation + a simple example showing the difference.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365728(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is still not clear what are the differences ..

Comment: GetLogicalDrives returns the mapped drives. Volumes are different altogether. You can map a drive to a volume, or map a drive to a folder on a volume. Volumes don't need to be mapped.

Comment: Volumes do not have to have a drive letter, and drive letters can refer to things besides volumes (i.e. network shares).

Answer (score 0):

**GetLogicalDrives** returns bitmask value (which u can consider binary representation of an integer). this number, while tracing from left to write in binary format, gives you if the corresponding driver is present or not starting from A:. 
e.g. If you get the return value as 12, i.e. 1100, this shows tracing from left, A, and B drives are not present and C and D drives are present.

> GetLogicalDrives doesn't include information related to system recovery volumes or
>   windows reserved.

Whereas **FindFirstVolume+FindNextVolume** gives all the volumes present including Windows reserved and system recovery partition. the return value is a unique GUID for the volume which can also be found in registry.(HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\CPC\Volume)